# Shutdown hook exits automatically when debugging it

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

I set a breakpoint in the shutdown hook, and debug it in intellij. But it looks like it has some timeout that it would automatically exit after some time.

Answer (score 0):

In cases of System Shutdown, operating system allows a fixed amount of time for shutdown and exit. In other cases application waits for shutdown-hook to complete like `ctrl C` , `System.exit(status)`

It is expected that shutdown-hook to finish their work quickly.